# Meta viewport on different browsers

Tags: html, meta

I'm using the line

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;">
```

but it doesn't seem to want to actually work in dolphin or the android stock browsers.

has anyone had this experience or is viewport just not compatible with those browsers?

EDIT:  I am looking to set the browser to show 100% of the page, no zoom, just page.  Setting the scale does the reverse of what I need and the users need to be able to zoom.

Comment: Try this:  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

Comment: That doesn't really do what I want though, I want the page width to be the device width so the viewport has to load that way.  That line just sets the scale to zoomed in....

Answer (score 0):

[W3C *recommends* this](http://www.w3.org/TR/mwabp/#bp-viewport):

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

> yes, I am aware, that it is from 2010 but I couldn't find a newer version

And it works for all androids I ever tested; also for dolphin. If you want to be *really* sure that even very outdated microsoft devices get it, you could also add:

```html
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true"/>
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320"/>
```

At least it won't hurt to use all three, even though probably the last two will almost never be relevant.

EDIT: Turns out the opposite of what `width=device-width` does is requested. The thing is: Having zoomed out is the default behavior of every mobile browser, considering the content *doesn't fit*. Anything else would be counterproductive. I tried it with dolphin on various sites without any viewport-meta and it works as intended. So *your content actually seems to fit*, what means your documents `width` is indeed equal to or smaller than the `device-width`. That is for example the case, if you ...

- ... float crucial elements of your page contents
- ... fill your content via JavaScript (/Ajax) afterwards
- ... have crucial elements absolute positioned
- ... have negative margins on some crucial elements in your content
- ... have a dynamic page width, that scales to the windows width

Of course there are more possibilities. Unfortunately `body { min-width: 800px; }` (or whatever you want to be the min-width) is the only solution that comes to my mind, at the moment.

If your content has a static width, you could try

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=980px" />
```

with `980px` being your page width. But actually in that case, the documents width should be at least `980px` anyway. So the viewport width should not be possible to achieve what you want.

Comment: that viewport won't do what I need though.  I want the scale NOT to be set.  I just need the page to load at 100% of it's content width wise.

Comment: @GaelenN Your request states clearly, that you want the documents width to be equal to the devices width. That is exactly the definition of `width=device-width`. This leads to the axiomatic consequence, that parts of the users screen are unusable if he zoomed out. Having zoomed out in turn is the *default state* of a mobile browsers page viewing. Could you explain why *anybody ever* would want unusable areas around a page that itself is exactly as wide as the phones screen but *zoomed out* and thus very thin?

Comment: if the default state of the browser was zoome dout then I wouldn't need this line.  Problem is not all browsers consider this a default so I need to force it, the page HAS to load in it's full capacity via the clients instructions.  I'm just trying to figure out how to force that to happen.

Comment: @GaelenN Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks @Matmarbon I think I have if figured out.  I'll post more once i get it through QA.